# Do android phones sync with Ubuntu?

Tags: sync, android

Some models only or all models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said, it's seen like an USB drive by Ubuntu, but the system is designed to sync over the net. Most of the stuff don't need a computer, for example my contacts and phone numbers sync with my gmail and facebook account. Pics with picassa, Files with Dropbox, task with Remember the Milk, etc...

I really only attach it to a computer to make backups when I do system updates (I own a HTC Magic with the latest Cyanogenmod RC). All the other syncing is done magically over the net.

Comment: I still think syncing my playlist with Rythmbox is very usefull...

Comment: and shotwell photo manager does a nice job too for syncing pictures.

Answer (score 3):

I only tested with one model (Motorola Milestone, called "Droid" in the US). But as far as I know, this is true for every android phone.

It actually syncs very well. It is seen as a USB drive by the system, but Ubuntu finds it has pictures and music on it, and then you can access it through Rythmbox and F-Spot, and synchronize your music and photos with it very easily.

Answer (score 2):

Android phones aren't like iPhones. They don't require a client running on your computer to sync, instead they tend to sync with online services over the air (via wifi or cell network).

Having said that, there is a Dropbox client for Android that will sync your files without requiring you to plug your phone in.

Answer (score 0):

Syncing over the net with google services is much more useful that by cabel.
You can sync you calendar, contacts, tasks and much more with Ubuntu, Thunderbird and other apps.